# Instructions on an assignement on dev c++

Tags: dev-c++

So it has been a week since I started using dev c++ and our teacher gave us 2 excercises. I am new to the whole programming thing so I would like some help. The first excercise is about making a program with which you input integers until the sum surpasses 100. Then it should output the total sum and the amount of numbers inputed. The second one says: input 10 integers and show how many times the user has inputed consecutive numbers. For example: -5, 10, 17, -31, -30, -29, 75, 76, 9, -4 the program should show Pair=3 because of : {-31, -30}, {-30, -29} and {75, 76}. I think I have done the first one since the output screen shows exactly what our teacher wants but I am curious if there are any mistakes. But for the second I can't find a way to increase the number of pairs everytime the user inputs 2 consecutive numbers

1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()  {
int x,numbers,sum=0;
  do{
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    sum+=x;
          if(sum<100){
        numbers++;
        }   }
    while(sum<100);

   printf("Sum: %d\t Numbers: %d",sum,numbers); 
   return(0);
   }
```

2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()

{
int i,number,pairs=0;

for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
  printf("Enter number: \n");
  scanf("%d",&number);}
  if(number+=number);
     {
      pairs++;} 
    printf("Pairs: %d\n",pairs);
return(0);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For (1):
You only increment numbers if the sum is less than 100. So if the first number is greater than 100, you output "Sum: 100   Numbers: 0", even though numbers=1.

For (2):
This simply won't work. Since this is an assignment, I'll just recommend you keep track of three things: the last seen number, the current number, and the number of consecutive pairs seen.

Comment: You are right. I set numbers=1 so now it shows the correct amount of numbers inputed, even if the first is greater than 100.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find a way to increase the amount of consecutive pairs eveytime there is one. I tried many different ways but it only shows 1. I will keep on trying and hope I get some results.

Comment: Your attempt tracks only remembers one number at a time. You need to track remember at least the last two to tell when a consecutive pair has occurred.